# How can I make a button change text in a nearby element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dom, frontend

Currently I have a script that programmatically creates a number of panels (yeah, Twitter Bootstrap panels) on a page using jQuery. They're all basically the same, except there's some dynamic text inside each one and below the text there is a button. Kinda like this:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
    <div class="panel-body">There's some dynamically-generated text here.</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Click Here</button>
    </div>            
</div>
```

So I'm trying to write an onclick method for the button that will grab that panel-body up above it and then replace the text inside it. The replacing-text function is no problem, but I'm having a devil of a time writing the proper jQuery to grab the right element.

**What I've Tried**

First I tried to use "this" as a context but, as expected, that didn't work.

```
$(".panel-body", this).text(updateContent())
```

I know this will work:

```
$("#panel1 .panel-body").text(updateContent())
```

So I tried dynamically building that selector in the same loop I build the ids, but with all the single quotes and double quotes and plus signs I just could not get the javascript to parse the line correctly.

I'm sure the solution is simple, but my eyes are crossing and I can't quite see it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `this` is your button element, then try

```
$(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-body').text("foobar")
```

The advantage of using `closest()` is that you can nest your button arbitrarily deep without needing to change your handler.

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('.panel .btn').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.panel').find('.panel-body').text('foobar');
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
    <div class="panel-body">There's some dynamically-generated text here.</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Click Here</button>
    </div>            
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
    <div class="panel-body">There's some dynamically-generated text here.</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Click Here</button>
    </div>            
</div>
<div class="panel panel-default" id="panel1">
    <div class="panel-body">There's some dynamically-generated text here.</div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-block">Click Here</button>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$(this).parent().prev().html("updated content");
```

Comment: Gahhhhhh how did I forget about .prev()?! #noobMistake

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close, instead of using `this` directly, you need to find the parent panel first by using `closest`:

```
$(".panel-body", $(this).closest('div.panel')).text(updateContent())
```